# CentOS VitualBox Downgrade

Tags: centos7, virtualbox, vagrant

I got a linux CentOS 7 as a host for virtual machines enviroments, mostly Windows. I use VirtualBox with Vagrant to build the machines. Lately I upgraded both: VirtualBox from 5.2.18 to 5.2.22 and Vagrant form 2.2.0 to 2.2.1, after i did this Vagrant won't communicate trought winrm communicator to set the networks adapters ip, giving me the error:

> "Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that 
>   Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within  the
>   configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period"

I tried to solve this problem by modifying the "config.vm.boot_timeout" and "config.winrm.timeout" values to no avail.

I want to downgrade the virtualbox to it's previous version, How can i do this in CentOS 7?

PD: The host doesn't have a gui.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the problem was in the new version of Vagrant, I tested both in combination with other versions of respective software, for some reason Vagrant 2.2.1 It wont play well with the last version of Virtualbox, I did not have problems with Virtualbox. 
I just uninstalled  Vagrant 2.2.1 and installed the 2.2.0 version, problem solved.